# Earned "down-vote" - with not enough reputation

Tags: support, privileges

My reputation is currently 121. 
In my achievements, last entry states that I earned the right to down vote.

When I click on "learn more" I read, that this right requires 125 reputation...

So - why do I have it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could have *briefly* gained a reputation if someone upvoted a post you made, then un-upvoted again. This can also happen for an accept-unaccept vote pair.

In that case you reach 126, 131 or 146 for a brief moment (depending on the type of vote), you get the privilege plus message, then you lose it again.

As you [Stack Overflow reputation history for today](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3626632/ngulam?tab=reputation) contains a *There were no net reputation changes on this day* entry, this is all the more likely. That entry only appears if there was a vote *at first* but has since been retracted. Any votes cast on your posts, that are retracted on the same day, are not shown in your record, to keep the record clean and uncluttered. Most likely this happened for your [most recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997086/converting-datetime-to-strptime/24997300#24997300).

You'll soon enough reach 125 points again, at which point the privilege will be back. You'll not get the message a second time, however.

Comment: shouldn't I see an upvoted, then retracted entry in reputation history?

Comment: @ngulam: not if they happened in the same day.

Comment: Sometimes you'll briefly see both even in the same day.  Might be a bug, but I've had it happen.  They usually combine and go away 20 minutes later or so